# Selenium Webdriver Element not exists condition fails

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have a If Else block within a while block. If element is present, click it to remove it and put it back to parent list. Else if element is not in the list then select from parent list and put it back.

The first time it works. It sees that the element is present, clicks it to removes it. On the second pass it fails when checking for the element
I tried with FindElement.IsDisplayed and !=null.

I get this exception :

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == select[id="idSelSelectedLanes"]>option[value="9012"] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 30.16 seconds
```

What am I missing?

*This is my first post here so apologize for any formatting issues.*

thanks

```
count ++;
if(count % 2 == 0){  
    if(BROWSER.equals("IE")) {
       // check if 9012 is present
        if(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[id=\"idSelSelectedLanes\"]>option[value=\"9012\"]"))!=null){
            try {
               // since its present, click to remove
               driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[id=\"idSelSelectedLanes\"]>option[value=\"9012\"]")).click();;
               Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
               System.out.println("Couldn't remove 9012");
            }
        } else  {
            try {
               //Not present, so select from Available Lanes    
               driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[id=\"idSelAvailableLanes\"]>option[value=\"9012\"]")).isDisplayed();
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
               System.out.println("Couldn't add 9012");                            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `driver.findElement(...)` in a `try-catch` block

```
count ++;
WebElement e;
if(count % 2 == 0) {
    if(BROWSER.equals("IE")) {
        // check if 9012 is present
        try {
            e = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[id=\"idSelSelectedLanes\"]>option[value=\"9012\"]"));
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            e.click()
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't remove 9012");
            // the else part goes here
        }
    }
}
```

Another approach is to use `findElements` instead of `findElement` to avoid the try-catch, and use `.get(0)` to get the element you want.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, you should check elementExist first using findElements, if it exists -> perform other actions

```
count ++;
WebElement e;
String e9012Css = "select[id=\"idSelSelectedLanes\"]>option[value=\"9012\"]";
if(count % 2 == 0) {
    if(BROWSER.equals("IE")) {
    // check if 9012 is present
        e9012Existed = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(e9012Css)).size() > 0;
        if(e9012Existed) {
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(e9012Css)).Click();
        } 
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Couldn't remove 9012");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use isElementPresent

```
if(isElementPresent(By.cssSelector("select[id=\"idSelSelectedLanes\"]>option[value=\"9012\"]"))){
  // since its present, click to remove 
} else {
  //Not present, so select from Available Lanes 
}
```